# C# - Convert a string [ Month DD, YYYY ] to DateTime

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to convert a string with this format `Month DD, YYYY` to a **DateTime** object, and performance is so important here.

String examples:

```
string AlaaJoseph = "October 23, 1996";
string JennetteMcCurdy = "June 26, 1992";
```

Comment: Just curious, why performance is so important in this case?

Comment: Did you used the below one

    string AlaaJoseph = "October 23, 1996";

    var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(AlaaJoseph);

Comment: Although it sounds strange that you say performance is important, if that really is the case then a home-made parser would probably be faster than the built-in DateTime.Parse() methods. Assuming you have full control over the validity of the input, so you don't have to test for faulty input.

Comment: @RenniePet that could be viewed as micro optimization (at least in my case).

Comment: @Cole "Cole9" Johnson: No it can't when the OP says that performance is important.

Comment: @Jason [String concatenation performance is important to me!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("October 23, 1996",
                                  "MMMM d, yyyy",
                                  new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at using something like

[DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified array of formats,
>   culture-specific format information, and style. The format of the
>   string representation must match at least one of the specified formats
>   exactly. The method returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.

Something like

```
string AlaaJoseph = "October 23, 1996";
DateTime AlaaJosephDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(AlaaJoseph, "MMMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out AlaaJosephDateTime))
    Console.WriteLine("DateTimeTryParseExact Passed");

string JennetteMcCurdy = "June 26, 1992";
DateTime JennetteMcCurdyDateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(JennetteMcCurdy, "MMMM dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out JennetteMcCurdyDateTime))
    Console.WriteLine("DateTimeTryParseExact Passed");
```

Also, another good thing to know about is [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can Do in this way:

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("October 23, 1996",
                                      "MMMM d, yyyy",
                                      new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

> performance is so important here

i Think performance is of secondary importance. Proper functioning of program in all scenarios is foremost. if it is fast in one scenario and fails on nine than it is useless to have a fast program. You should first make your program to work in all scenarios and then consider making if optimised. Even if you write your own parser to parse string you will still have to do all exception handling at any stage.

So, instead of reinventing the wheel and to ensure that you don't have to deal with any sort of exception handling and let the framework do that for you. You should use

```
DateTime.TryParseExact
```

it also has an overload that takes string[] formats where you can specify all the formats that you expect user to give

```
string[] formats= {"MMMM dd, yyyy","MMM dd, yyyy","M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
               "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
               "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
               "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm"};

DateTime resultantDate;
string AlaaJoseph = "October 23, 1996";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(AlaaJoseph, formats, 
                          new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, 
                          out resultantDate))
{
     //your rest of code
}
```